# Jackrabbit 2.8.1 to Oak 1.4.1 migration

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

When trying to execute migration command:

```
java -jar oak-upgrade-1.4.1.jar D:/data/temp/jackrabbit mongodb://localhost:27017/oak
```

yields failed to copy content error;

In repository.xml reference is:

```
<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager">
    <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:D:/data/jackrabbit/workspaces/default/db;create=true"/>
    <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="default_"/>
    <param name="bundleCacheSize" value="256"/>
    <param name="consistencyCheck" value="false"/>
    <param name="minBlobSize" value="16384"/>
    <param name="driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
    <param name="user" value=""/>
    <param name="password" value=""/>
    <param name="errorHandling" value=""/>
    <param name="derbyStorageInitialPages" value="32"/>
    <param name="derbyStorageMinimumRecordSize" value="256"/>
    <param name="derbyStoragePageCacheSize" value="4096"/>
    <param name="derbyStoragePageReservedSpace" value="40"/>
    <param name="derbyStoragePageSize" value="32768"/>
</PersistenceManager>
```

Since Derby is embedded and during migration, oak is expecting derby server to be up and running;

Kindly advise on migration options.

*Note:Same question requested in jackrabbit forum as well, but there is no response.*

Comment: Hi, were you able to migrate to Oak ? I am myself doing the migration from JCR2 to Oak, and have folowing questions:

1. JCR 2.0  stores data in Oracle, do we need to migrate that to Oracle?
2. JCR 2.0 stores indexes in File System, do we even need to copy those to MongoDB?, anyways Oak will automatically build the indexes.